# Smoothly resizing navigation view when toolbar or navigation bar animates on or off screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm animating a UINavigationController navigation bar and toolbar on and off screen. That works as expected -- but the view contained between them doesn't change size smoothly.

The bars animate on and off as they should, but the navigation view between them jumps from the reduced size (when both bars are visible) to the full screen size (when they're hidden).

Purely as a guess, I've tried this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

...but it doesn't make any difference.

Is there any way to get the navigation view to change size smoothly?

I can solve the problem by using `animated:NO` so that **everything** jumps, but that looks ugly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to create a smooth view transition:

1) In Interface Builder, the view which basically in between of the navbar and toolbar, should not automatically resize its content (eg a picture) so I unticked Autoresize Subviews flag

2) Then created the following touch handler for the hide/unhide event. The key point is using the

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
     duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
     animations:^
     {
         /* Put other animation code here ;) */
     }];
```

code snippet to add extra animation for the built-in hide/unhide animations.

Originally I tried simple: hide/unhide the two bars and let iOS resize the inner view. The result (on Simulator) was disappointing, it was not smooth. If I did only one bar hide, it did well the view resizing, but not with two bars in the code.

So here's the full touchedBegun event handler which does the trick:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (blVisible) {
        [app.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [app.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                          duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                        animations:^
         {
             /* Put other animation code here ;) */
             self.img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
         }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];


    } else {
        [app.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [app.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                          duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                        animations:^
         {
             /* Put other animation code here ;) */
             self.img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 387);
         }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];

    }
    blVisible = !blVisible;
}
```

One small comment: it is smooth now, but in Simulator what I see is that iOS somehow hides/unhides the two bars not in-sync so the view resize is not perfectly timed. Pls check on device too.

If you want more perfect solution I think you have to implement the bars for your own to fully controll their hiding/unhiding effect...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I tried your approach, and it improved things a bit -- but sadly it doesn't solve the problem. After many different experiments, the view will only animate smoothly in one direction -- i.e. I can get it to grow smoothly upwards as the navigation bar hides, but the bottom of the view jumps down before the bottom toolbar has moved off screen. I think your comment about implementing it yourself to find a perfect solution is probably correct... iOS doesn't seem to have a way of smoothly hiding both bars simultaneously.

Comment: When I wanted in an other project to push viewA (without navbar) to viewB (with navbar) and enable during the push anim the unhide it was also disappointing how iOS handles this so I decided to make the iOS navbar always hidden to use its push/pop features and implement a custom navbar...

Comment: I think you can play with this solution more eg: 1) do the bars hide/unhide and keep view still then after resize the view smoothly or 2) during the hide/unhide action alter the view's alpha to 0.4 and then again to 1.0 which cosmetics the small unperfection of this solution. Finally I think @James if you got the full perspective of your question in this answer you should accept it to help others too...

Answer (score 0):

Within that animation block, you could try setting the frame of your in-between view to what it should be after the bars are hidden.  That should make the transition smooth.